# If $A(1,p^2), B(0,1)$ and $C(p,0)$ are the coordinates of three points, then the value of p for which area of ABC is min

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems, area

If $A(1,p^2), B(0,1)$ and $C(p,0)$ are the coordinates of three points, then the value of p for which area of ABC is minimal.

Using the formula for area 
$$\Delta =\frac 12[1(1)+0+p(p^2-1)]$$
Taking its derivative

$$\frac {d \Delta}{dp}=\frac 12 [3p^2-1]=0$$
$$p=\frac {1}{\sqrt 3}$$

The options were, $\frac {1}{\sqrt 3} , \frac{-1}{\sqrt 3} , \frac {1}{\sqrt 2}$ while the fourth option is ‘None of these’. Fourth option is right. Why is that so?

*I checked around, and the reasoning given is that the value of the triangle will be minimum when the points are collinear ie. area of triangle is zero. It seems plausible but kinda defeats the purpose of the question. If we go with the collinearity reason, no values in the option satisfy the equation. However, I feel $\frac {1}{\sqrt 3} should be the minim value in case the pints are ‘not’ collinear.*

Comment: You should add an absolute value because the area is also positive. Also, what does „the right answer is neither“ mean?

Comment: is that possible you have a mistake?

first, what are the correct values of each point? what are the values you got?

second, which formula are you using to calculate the area? could you give a reference to it? isn't the area of a triangular is a height times base?

Comment: @Jneven https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

Comment: $\Delta$ in terms of $p$ is a cubic function, so there is a $p$ that makes $\Delta = 0$. Now the problem is solving the cubic equation...

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit I don’t have the answer because it wasn’t in the option

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit quite low, the answer is none of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is as follows: Since the three vertices can be collinear (when $p = p_0$ satisfies $p_0^3 + 1 = p_0$), as $p$ approaches this $p_0$ the area of the triangle approaches zero. So the area can reach every arbitrarily small positive number, but never zero itself, since in the case of collinear vertices $ABC$ is no longer a triangle and therefore does not have a well-defined area. Hence there is no minimum area.

Comment: That can work. But does this apply to all coordinates or is this question a special case? Does it have anything to with it being a cubic polynomial?

Comment: It doesn't relate to it being a cubic polynomial. Basically, if you set the coordinates of the vertices as continuous functions of some variable $p$, and there is at least one value of $p$ for which the three vertices are collinear, then the same argument applies.

Comment: But there is a value for p for which area of triangle is zero, which contradicts your answer

Comment: When the three points are on a line, the area is normally considered to be undefined and not zero. Even if you wish to call the area zero in this situation, since the value of $p$ for which the points are collinear was not one of your options "none of these" would still be the correct answer.